# When generating Entities from an Existing Database, how to modify / create manyToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine

[Here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html), there's an explanation on "How to generate Entities from an Existing Database".

I have a table `person`. And a table `address`. A person can have many different addresses, and an address can be related to one ore more persons. So this is a "many to many" relationship. Thus I've created an "in-between" table I've called `personaddress` where there's a idPersonne and idAddress.

When launching the generation everything is fine but the many to many relationship (there are more than one).

```
PersonneAdresse:
    type: entity
    table: personne_adresse
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
            type: bigint
            nullable: false
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    manyToOne:
        idPersonne:
            targetEntity: Personne
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                id_personne:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        idAdresse:
            targetEntity: Adresse
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                id_adresse:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

The documentation about oneToMany is not enough (I need an example to understand):

> If you have oneToMany relationships between your entities, you will
>   need to edit the generated xml or yml files to add a section on the
>   specific entities for `oneToMany` defining the `inversedBy` and the
>   `mappedBy` pieces.

And I'm pretty sure the modification is not only about oneToMany, but manyToMany too.
Can you explain me what I should do/modify to be able to generate properly the corresponding entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did the stuff: I've generated the whole files, but I knew there were some ManyToMany relationships. So I declared them "manually" in the corresponding files. Then I've encountered another problem. In the documentation, the codes samples aren't 100% correct. You have to do this add "`@ORM\`" instead of the simple "`@`". Here my code that works:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Adresse", inversedBy="personnes")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="personne_adresse")
 **/
private $adresses;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Partenaire", inversedBy="personnes")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="personne_partenaire")
 **/
private $partenaires;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Telephone", inversedBy="personnes")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="personne_telephone")
 **/
private $telephones;

public function __construct() {
    $this->adresses = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->partenaires = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->telephones = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Moreover, you have to delete corresponding ManyToMany Php files, because Symfony 2 (I guess) handle those "in-between" ManyToMany tables itself => no need to declare. In my sample, I had to delete "`PersonneAdresse.php`", "`PersonnePartenaire.php`" and "`PersonneTelephone.php`".